# Javascript 'Multiple Click Simulation' issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to simulate multiple button-type clicks with Javascript, the webpage I'm running it on has around 10 of 1 type of button and 1 of the other.

I'm wanting the JS to click ALL of the buttons on the webpage that match the markup of the first button, then after that's completed, finally click the other.

I've managed to get it to easily click all 10 of the first button, but I'm starting to struggle with the other button.
The markup for the first button is this; http://pastebin.com/aRNpjG0n

So running this Javascript, I am able to click these buttons with a 2 second delay;

```
 window.setInterval( function(){ 
    var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('x-button-litebutton-wrapper'); 
    for(
            var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++
        )
            {inputs[i].click();}
    }, 
    2000);
```

The markup for the other button is available here; http://pastebin.com/baw32HjK

I'm assuming the ID for the second button is 'x-btn-text', if that's the case, then my issue would simply be how to implament it within my existing Javascipt (Above)

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, since I've not managed to find anything on here about simulating more than 1 button click at a time.

Comment: You are clicking *all 10 buttons at once* after 2 seconds. Is that the intention?

Comment: I'm clicking all of the 10 buttons that match the first markup, followed by the 1 button that follows the first markup, the 2 seconds is a random value that I added for the sake of this post. @TrueBlueAussie

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your problem actually is, but here is a version in jQuery (to keep it simpler):

http://jsfiddle.net/t9r4ru0m/

```
$(function () {

    // Debug - write out log that the items were clicked
    $('.x-button-litebutton-wrapper').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
    });
    $('.x-btn-text').click(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr('class'));
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('clicking');
        $('.x-button-litebutton-wrapper').click();

        // Now click the rest of the buttons
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.x-btn-text').click();
        }, 3000);
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I went on a bit in my original post lol, but my issue is really putting it all together into 1 Javascript statement, rather than 2 separate ones, so it would run through and click the 10 buttons, then finally the other.

Comment: A callback in a callback is your best bet. You can of course just click them all at the same time in jQuery with `$('.x-button-litebutton-wrapper,.x-btn-text').click()` :)